# Why SQL float maps to Java double instead of Java float?

Tags: java, sql, types, floating-point, sqldatatypes

As part of my graduation thesis, I'm looking up how SQL standard types (not implementation-specific types) map to Java types. Most of it are no-brainers but I noticed one thing: SQL `float` is listed everywhere as mapping to Java `double`, but I can't find any explanation as to *why*.

As far as I know, both SQL and Java `float` types are 32-bit single-precision floating points as specified in IEEE-754. So why the casting into 64-bit double-precision when the source isn't using that level of precision either? Is there a risk of overflowing the variable or is it "better safe than sorry" prompted by `float`'s inherent imprecision when it comes to large/small values?

Comment: I don't know  from where you have it that SQL `float` is an IEEE-754 float. For example https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp states that SQL `float` has a mantissa with 16 digits, which in Java is only possible with `double`

Comment: @Thomas: indeed. And "DOUBLE PRECISION" has the same. So mapping to `double` in Java seems correct.

Comment: A quick glance over that w3schools shows _several_ errors and omissions, plus failure to correctly distinguish what various vendors do things.

Comment: I don't know Java's rationale.  MySQL simply implemented both 32-bit (`FLOAT`) and 64-bit (`DOUBLE`) formats.  There are situations where it uses Double tmp values and literals, which can be confusing with stored Floats.  Also `FLOAT(m)` (in MySQL) first rounds to decimal, then stores in binary.  (So this comment points out 2-3 errors in w3schools.)